# iframe in CSS table layout

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to have a youtube video side by side with some text. My HTML is the following (http://jsfiddle.net/N5j7L/):

```
<div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="width: 600px; display: table-cell;">
            something</br>
            something</br>
            something</br>
            something</br>
            something</br>
            something</br>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;"> 
            <iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gDNsePOQVzU&list=UUoUXxtd712vGe5p5lBk_eMg?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I do not understand why the first column starts lower than the second one. Should I add something to CSS? Without `iframe` everything looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (added vertical-align:top for the left column):

```
<div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
                        <div style="display: table-row">
                            <div style="width: 600px; display: table-cell; vertical-align:top;">
                                something<br/>
                                something<br/>
                                something<br/>
                                something<br/>
                                something<br/>
                                something<br/>
                            </div>
                            <div style="display: table-cell;"> 
                                <iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gDNsePOQVzU&list=UUoUXxtd712vGe5p5lBk_eMg?rel=0"                 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use a table. If it isn't a restriction, then the following works.

```
<table cellpadding="15">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gDNsePOQVzU&list=UUoUXxtd712vGe5p5lBk_eMg?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br/>
            Video 1
        </td>

        <td>
            <iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gDNsePOQVzU&list=UUoUXxtd712vGe5p5lBk_eMg?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
            <br/>
            Video 2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N5j7L/4/

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with simple flow layout. Flow your description to the left. then set a margin to the iframe container as width as your text block:

```
<div style="overflow: auto;">
    <div style="width: 100px; float: left;">
        <!-- text -->
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 100px;"> 
        <iframe ...></iframe> 
    </div>
</div>
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/N5j7L/1/